# Javascript calling php function with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to show content on subfolders on my website.
So far I have a SelectBox wich outputs the name of folders, I need (on the onchange event) to show files in that folder.

My select:

```
<select name="imgfolder" onchange="filelist(this.value)">
```

Filelist is a JavaScript in the same page, which calls a php function in another file:

```
<script>    
    function filelist(selectedData)
    {       
        $.ajax({      
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://www.example.com/filelist.php',   

    dataType: 'json',    
    data: { folder: selectedData },
    success: function(response) 
    {        
    alert (response);

    }
    });

    }
</script>
```

And finally filelist.php page:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');


  $folder = $_POST['folder'];
  echo json_encode($folder);

?>
```

At the moment it should simply return the name of the folder which is passed from JavaScript back to the caller and display an alert...
But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: You are using JQuery Code for AJAX call not plain JS..Make sure your JQuery is working fine

Comment: For starters, you're only handling `success` case of the ajax call.  If it fails, you're not doing anything to expose the failure message.  Add some handling for failures, or for debugging, at least change `success` to `complete` and maybe you'll see more about what's happening.

Comment: jQuery *is* JS @ShaileshSingh

Comment: Yeah you are right but what i meant is there might be the JQuery library problem because code seems good @JayBlanchard

Comment: @Antonio until you answer the questions in the first comment there is no way we can know how to help you. *"Help us to help you."*

Comment: I see an error saying "TypeError: $.ajax is not a function"
no other errors.
Jquery appears to be loaded by the template of my website...

Comment: changing $.ajax to jQuery.ajax did the trick. 
I am in Joomla and there are more tahn one jQuery imports I beleieve, and also the jQuery NoConflict plugin whcih should sole these kind of issues...